# ¿Que son las llamadas externas & internas en HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy siguiendo unos conceptos sobre fundamentos de diseño web estructurados.

En lo largo de la escritura encontré la siguiente frase "llamadas externas" & "llamadas internas".

Esta frase me esta traumatizando, llevo haciendo tantas vinculaciones que a la hora de la hora no le toma importancia hasta que una cierta frase te mantiene en la **incognita.**

La externa, entiendo que es lo que está fuera del cuerpo.

**Ejemplo**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../1/2/style.css">
```

Y las llamadas internas son los estilos dentro del cuerpo.

> En llamadas de `PHP` me imagino que el concepto se asimila igual

¿Me pueden explicar más a fondo este tema?

Answer (score 1):

las llamdas de ficheros se hacen entravez de

```
<?php include("inclues/funciones.php");
//o tambien 
require_once("inc/funciones.php");

?>
```